# Using versions environment tags inside a new environment definition

Tags: environments, conditionals

I just found out about the `versions` package here and am interested in using it to hide solutions in a problem set document. Recall that, to create versions block, in the preamble, you need

```
\usepackage{versions}  
\excludeversion{sol}  
%\includeversion{sol}
```

and, in the document,

```
\begin{sol} ... \end{sol}
```

Here, the blocks labeled "sol" will be excluded.

In my document, I define a new environment "Solution" as

```
\newenvironment{Solution}{\begin{sol} \\ \textbf{Solution: }}{\end{sol}}
```

This construction works perfectly if I instruct LaTeX to include the "sol" blocks, but chokes if I try to exclude them. For example, the following code chokes and gives an `Incomplete \iffalse` error:

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{versions}  
\excludeversion{sol}  
%\includeversion{sol}  
\newenvironment{Solution}{  
  \begin{sol}\\ \textbf{Solution: }}{  
  \end{sol}}  
\begin{document}  
\section{Question 1}  
What is $2+2$?  
\begin{Solution}  
It is $2+2=4$.  
\end{Solution}  
\end{document}
```

If I change the commenting and include "sol", then this code works as expected. I'm guessing that there's something going on with the way that the versions package works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Another useful-looking package that I'd never heard of!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't use `\begin{sol} ... \end{sol}` in the definition of the Solution environment.  `\begin ... \end` blocks don't nest very well.  Rather, use `\sol ... \endsol`.  Thus:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{versions}
\excludeversion{sol}
%\includeversion{sol}
\newenvironment{Solution}{
\sol\\ \textbf{Solution: }}{
\endsol}
\begin{document}
\section{Question 1}
What is $2+2$?
\begin{Solution}
It is $2+2=4$.
\end{Solution}
\end{document}
```

works.