# How to use an environment defined by the versions-package inside another environment

Tags: environments, versions

When I use the [versions](http://ctan.org/pkg/versions) package to conditionally exclude content like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}% just as example

\usepackage[tracing]{versions}
\excludeversion{vers}% opposite to \includeversion{vers}

\newenvironment{test}{%
START%
\vers%
\color{red}%
}{%
\endvers%
END% is excluded but should not be excluded 
}

\begin{document}
before

\begin{test}
% content is excluded for \excludeversion{vers}
%        and included for \includeversion{vers} above
inside
\end{test}

after
\end{document}
```

I can exclude the content of the `vers` environment, as intended by the use of the `versions` package. But also `END` gets excluded (after `\endvers`), opposed to my intention. With `\includeversion{vers}` also `END` gets included (as intended). What do I do wrong, and how do I fix it?

It is possible to define

```
\newcommand{\afterendvers}{%
END% and all other stuff I want to have executed here
}
```

and replace `\end{test}` by `\end{test}\afterendvers` in the whole document, but a more "TeXnical" solution would be nice.

Related issue: With `\includeversion{vers}` `END` is printed in red, although

> environments processed as if `\begin{<version>}` and `\end{<version>}`
>   just were not present, however they form groups like
>   `\begin{relax} <code> \end{relax}` or `\begingroup  <code>  \endgroup`

(from the versions manual), but

```
\vers%
\bgroup%
\color{red}%
}{%
\egroup%
\endvers%
END%
```

leads to `END` being written in black, as expected. I.e.: `\vers` and `\endvers` do not appear to act as `\begingroup` and `\endgroup` in this case.

Comment: When excluded `\vers` contains a `\let \end \fi` and `\iffalse`, so will ignore everything until the next `\end{<current environment>}`, where the current environment is set by the last `\begin`, i.e. `test` here. I don't think this `\end` is expanded, so the `\endvers%` and `END` is never seen.

Comment: Looking further at the source code it looks to me that `version` doesn't support such a usage.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: Thanks for the explanation! Then I will probably have to write to Uwe Lück (`versions` author) to either improve the package to support such nesting (without an idea how to do so) or to write a warning into the documentation - if no ingenious answer is given later.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I wrote an e-mail to Uwe Lück, the `versions` maintainer, and will give feed-back when I got an answer.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: OK, I got feedback by Uwe Lück. You are right, and at the moment there is no update of the package planned. Could you turn your first comment into an answer, please?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Using versions environment tags inside a new environment definition](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1720/2975)

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I was already using `\endvers` instead of `\end{vers}`, but the question linked by you is definitively related. Good to have the link here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs because when excluded `\vers` contains a `\let\end\fi` and `\iffalse`, so will ignore everything until the next `\end{<current environment>}`, where the current environment is set by the last `\begin`, i.e. `test` here. I don't think this `\end` is expanded, so the `\endvers%` and `END` in it is never seen.

I tried to figure out a way for this by looking at the source code of the `versions` package, but this just confirmed that such a usage is not supported by it. Larger rewrites of this package would be required for this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your actual use case is, but it seems like your MWE is supposed to conditionally color some text based on the version.  This works for me:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{color}% just as example
\usepackage[tracing]{versions}
\excludeversion{vers}

\def\colorbyversion{\normalcolor}
\begin{vers}
\gdef\colorbyversion{\color{red}}
\end{vers}

\newenvironment{test}{
START
\bgroup\colorbyversion}{%
\egroup
END% should not be excluded
}

\begin{document}
before

\begin{test}
inside
\end{test}

after
\end{document}
```

With `\includeversion{vers}`:

[image: sample document with vers included]

With `\excludeversion{vers}`:

[image: sample document with vers excluded]

The `\gdef` is needed to make the redefinition of `\colorbyversion` global.  Otherwise, the definition inside the `vers` environment dies at `\end{vers}`.

Comment: You should add `\ignorespaces` after `\colorbyversion` in the definition of `test`.

Comment: @Matthew Leingang: Unfortunately not. `color` really was an example. Your solution does not exclude `inside` with `\excludeversion{vers}`, as you wrote yourself.

Comment: @egreg: you are right.

Comment: @Stephen: Sorry about that.  Could you edit your question emphasizing the effect you want (and not just the implementation that isn't working)?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang: OK, I just did that now. By mentioning the versions package I had assumed everything was obvious, but of course I should not request people to guess about it, but write explicitly what I want to accomplish. Sorry that you had the work with the answer to the given instead of the intended question. (And here we always tell people that we are better with TeX than with mind-reading...)

Comment: @Stephen: Thanks.  Asking questions is tough.  I try to stick ESR's FAQ on how to ask a question, especially this part: [Describe the goal, not the step](http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal)